# xfce: cant change layout switch key due to unsupported keyboard model

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xfce

I prefer to use right alt as a keyboard layout (language) switch key. I use xfce. In keyboard settings I choose right alt as layout switch key - but is has no effect. I also notices that my keyboard model not in list provided in keyboard settings (Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000).

Can I add my keyboard model? How if so?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open Xfce 4 Settings Manager --- Menu --- Settings --- Xfce 4 Settings Manager

Click on the Keyboard icon.

Switch to the Layout tab.

Untick Use system defaults

Click the Add button and choose the appropriate keymap from the list.

Select the active layout.

If you need to switch between different layouts, installing the Xfce panel keyboard plugin might be a more convenient option.

Install xfce4-xkb-plugin from Ubuntu repos:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install xfce4-xkb-plugin
```

Right-click on the Xfce panel and choose Add new items

Select Keyboard and click Add

The keyboard plugin should appear in your panel.